# where are gwt-log log messages?

Tags: java, gwt, logging

I'm  trying to use gwt-log on my gwt application but I can't get any log message from this library( I don't know where should I found them) I have added these configuration to my gwt.xml file

```
  <inherits name="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-DEBUG" />

  <extend-property name="log_level" values="DEBUG"/>

  <set-property name="log_level" value="DEBUG"/>
  <set-property name="log_DivLogger" value="DISABLED" />
```

and I have modified my entry point class as follows:

```
 public void onModuleLoad() {
        Log.setUncaughtExceptionHandler();

        DeferredCommand.addCommand(new Command() {
            public void execute() {
                onModuleLoad2();
            }
        });
    }

        private void onModuleLoad2() {
         if (!Log.isLoggingEnabled()) {
              Window.alert("Logging is disabled. No log messages will appears.");
            }

                Log.trace("This is a 'TRACE' test message");
            Log.debug("This is a 'DEBUG' test message");
            Log.info("This is a 'INFO' test message");
            Log.warn("This is a 'WARN' test message");
            Log.error("This is a 'ERROR' test message");
            Log.fatal("This is a 'FATAL' test message");
            }
```

and I can get these messages printed on console but the problem is that I can't get any other message printed either in server side or in client side,So is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you setup the required [servlet](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/wiki/GettingStarted) in web.xml.

As a side note, if you are using GWT 2.1 or higher, you can start using the new [Logging](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html) framework, which emulates Java's built-in logging framework.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to see them in the development console (Jetty container wrap), in hosted mode. You can find a log of all HTTP traffic + gwt logs for a specific "host".

I'm not exactly sure how you can forward them to write to an external destination for production mode, though you should be able.